# Npgsql v5.0.0 GAC installation

Tags: .net, npgsql, gac

As given in the Npgsql version 5.0 release notes(Breaking changes) [here](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/release-notes/5.0.html), MSI GAC installer have been discontinued. The statement from the release notes is given below:

> Npgsql no longer targets .NET Framework 4.6.1. Since .NET Standard 2.0
> is targeted, it is still possible to use Npgsql from .NET Framework
> applications; however, we no longer run regression tests on .NET
> Framework and will only fix bugs on a best-effort basis. In addition,
> the Visual Studio extension (VSIX) and the MSI GAC installer have been
> discontinued. [#3269](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/3269).

The problem which I am facing owing to this change is that my clients were using the MSI installer to install the Npgsql in GAC and my application loads its factory dynamically using **System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories** of **.Net framework**. This gives me the flexibility to let the client choose their required provider version depending upon their database version.

Switching to the nuget package installation will add an overhead to update Npgsql packages within my application. Therefore, I want to avoid this route. Is there any way to still install the latest Npgsql 5.0 version in GAC as done by the MSI installer?

If yes, please let me know the steps to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I got it working by registering all the assemblies in GAC using gacutil.exe.

I am using .Net framework 4.6.1 in my application and I have performed the following steps to install the Npgsql version 5.0.0.0 in GAC:

1. Add the reference of the required version of the Npgsql .Net data provider in a new Visual Studio project.
2. Find and copy all the assemblies added by this provider in a folder.
3. Now we need to use gacutil.exe to register these assemblies in GAC. It can be used with Visual Studio command prompt or it comes with Windows SDK.
4. Use the command with Admin privileges and run the below command for each assembly.
   gacutil.exe /i "AssemblyPath/assemblyName.dll"

For the version 5.0.0.0, the complete list of commands are given below:

```
   gacutil.exe /i Npgsql.dll
   gacutil.exe /i Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll
   gacutil.exe /i System.Buffers.dll
   gacutil.exe /i System.Memory.dll
   gacutil.exe /i System.Numerics.Vectors.dll
   gacutil.exe /i System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll
   gacutil.exe /i System.Text.Encodings.Web.dll
   gacutil.exe /i System.Text.Json.dll  
   gacutil.exe /i System.Threading.Channels.dll
   gacutil.exe /i System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll
   gacutil.exe /i System.ValueTuple.dll
```

5. Now add the below entry in machine.config file at two locations

**Location 1:** `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config`

**Location 2:** `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config`

**Config Entry:**

```
 <system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories><add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description=".NET Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5D8B90D52F46FDA7"/></DbProviderFactories>
 </system.data>
```

6. In the current version 5.0.0.0, Npgsql is trying to find out the lower versions of dependent assemblies. I think this is a bug and they might fix this issue in later versions but for now we need to make some entries of the dependent assemblies in our application App.confg file to use these versions instead.

YourApplication.exe.config can be found in the installation directory and you need to add the below lines under the `<assemblyBinding>` section:

```
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.1" newVersion="4.2.0.1" />
</dependentAssembly>
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.5.0" newVersion="4.0.5.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="System.Buffers" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="System.Numerics.Vectors" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.4.0" newVersion="4.1.4.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Now I can easily get the *DbProviderFactory* instance in my application without any issue.

Answer (score -1):

Npgsql 5.0 no longer targets .NET Framework (the `net461` TFM), only the `netstandard2.0` TFM (as well as some newer ones). So it's no longer possible to install it into the GAC.

DbProviderFactories can still be used without the GAC - with either .NET Framework or .NET Core - but the Npgsql assembly will have to be distributed with the application or dropped into its directory as a "plugin".

Comment: That's my main concern, I want to avoid bundling Npgsql with my application otherwise I can easily bundle it using Nuget.

Comment: AFAIK, with Npgsql 5.0.0 there's no way to install it into the GAC. Bundling with the application (or allowing users to install it into your application somehow) is your only choice.

Comment: Since you are the owner of Npgsql, I have to believe that there's no other way :)
It's great to know that you are active here and it's certainly appreciable to get the answers directly from you. Thanks a lot for your time and help.

Comment: Thanks... What I can say for sure, is that Npgsql 5.0.0 no longer targets any .NET Framework TFM - only .NET Standard and .NET Core. What I'm less sure about is whether it's possible to install a netstandard2.0 assembly in the GAC - you can try that manually with gacutil -i

Comment: I got the DbProviderFactory instance by registering the Npgsql.dll 5.0.0.0 in GAC using gacutil and making an entry in machine.config file but it's throwing an error for the dependent files while performing any operation. Here's the error I got  *Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Channels, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'* Do I need to find out and register all the dependent assemblies in GAC as well?

Comment: Yes, you must install all the dependent assemblies into the GAC as well.

Comment: I got it working by registering all the assemblies in GAC using gacutil.exe and posted all the steps in my answer. Thanks again for your help.